# jQuery - clear all classes and ids of elment including children

Tags: jquery

I am trying to clear all classes and ids of an element and its children.
But my current code only clearing classes and ids only from the parent.

Please tell me how I clear all classes and ids of an element and its child.

Here is my code:

```
jQuery('#menu-main-menu').clone()
.removeAttr('id').removeAttr('class').prependTo('body');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will process all subordinate objects of the cloned tree:

```
jQuery('#menu-main-menu').clone().find("*")
    .removeAttr('id').removeAttr('class').end().prependTo('body');
```

If you also want to remove the attributes of the new parent, you can do this:

```
var clone = jQuery('#menu-main-menu').clone();
clone.add(clone.find("*")).removeAttr('id').removeAttr('class');
clone.prependTo('body');
```

A point to understand is that`.add()` creates a new jQuery object so the `clone` jQuery object is not affected by the `.add()`.

Comment: **+1** for `.end()`. Also, you missed the parent itself `;)`.

Comment: @NOX - was already working on an option to include the parent which is now in my answer too.

Answer (score 1):

You must remove `id` and `class` from childrens too:

```
var $elem = jQuery('#menu-main-menu').clone();
$elem.removeAttr('id').removeAttr('class');
$elem.find('*').removeAttr('id').removeAttr('class');
$elem.prependTo('body');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
jQuery('#menu-main-menu').clone().children().
.removeAttr('id').removeAttr('class').prependTo('body');
```

Comment: `.children()` only goes one level down.  It doesn't get the whole hierarchy.  You also aren't removing the class and id from the parent at the top of the cloned hierarchy.